# Can I get access rights back from users?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am considering to create an app for the first time and I am not sure I understand google‘s terms and conditions well. According to what I read, if I give access to some users, I will not be able to get it back and besides, google will get the right to distribute it further. Is this right?

Comment: Can you provide a link to "what you read"? Also, which kind of app are you talking about? An Addon? A Web App?

Comment: In the "Terms and conditions" I read for example:  ..... you grant google a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive, perpetual license to reproduce the Script .... distribute copies of the Script ...... Google has no responsibility for ensuring that the users previously granted access no longer use your Script .....                                                What I basically want to do is to make web app to do some calculations and display the results. I want to share this with certain people and password protect it and if necessary withdraw the access rights.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/terms

Comment: *What I basically want to do is to make web app to do some calculations and display the results. I want to share this with certain people and password protect it and if necessary withdraw the access rights.* That is possible as long as the implementation details are hidden in the server and not in the browser (html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a WebApp with limited access

When you [deploy a WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) you can choose how to execute the WebApp and who has access to it:

[image]

You execute either as

- You
- The user accessing the App

And the App can be accessed by either

- Only you
- Anyone in your domain
- Anyone

You are not able to select only specific users to have access.

- However, obviously only the users with whom you will share the WebApp URL will have access to it.
- Also, you can use within the WebApp the method [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) to retrieve the identity of the user and implement a conditional statement that runs the rest of the script only if the active user is one of the "allowed" ones.
- Very important: After deploying the WebApp for the first time, you can deploy it as a new version as often as desired and change thereby the execution and access permissions which makes it easy to revoke access

Comment: I guess the URL can be forwarded several times? And in the case accessible by "Anyone", how can I use the getActiveUser() method?

Comment: Yes, the URL can be forwarded. And `getActiveUser()` only works for your domain users. If this is not suitable for you you might want to think about a different approach, e.g. a Chrome Extension where you can retrieve the identity of a user with the Identity API or `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`. Or - instead of a WebApp you might prefer to share your Apps Script with selected users - you specify with whom you want to share the script, in the same way as you share any file on your Google Drive.